# USPS don't get all shipping options from reponse

Tags: usps

I am having a problem with USPS api. I contacted their support, but I got very disappointed response, they just said they do not provide technical support and send me the link to documentation. So the problem is that I don't get all methods back in their xml response.

Missing methods:
-Priority Mail Regional Rate
-Global Express Guaranteed
-Priority Mail Express International Flat Rate
-Priority Mail International Flat Rate

This is the request (change MY_USER_NAME):
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=RateV4&XML=%3C?xml%20version=%221.0%22%20encoding=%22UTF-8%22?%3E%3CRateV4Request%20USERID=%22MY_USER_NAME%22%3E%3CRevision%3E2%3C/Revision%3E%3CPackage%20ID=%220%22%3E%3CService%3EALL%3C/Service%3E%3CZipOrigination%3E19139%3C/ZipOrigination%3E%3CZipDestination%3E10003%3C/ZipDestination%3E%3CPounds%3E1%3C/Pounds%3E%3COunces%3E0%3C/Ounces%3E%3CContainer%3EVARIABLE%3C/Container%3E%3CSize%3EREGULAR%3C/Size%3E%3CMachinable%3Etrue%3C/Machinable%3E%3C/Package%3E%3C/RateV4Request%3E

Has anybody idea what is wrong, why I get just some methods back?

Comment: Did you find what was wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately not, my client didn't want to spend extra hours for further research. USPS wrote "...The USPS provides the Web Tools API service; however, we do not provide support for development and implementation.". All what I got is a link to their [documentation](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/Rate-Calculators-v1-8a.pdf).